# Calling Inherited Functions from Parent Class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a linked list class (List) that deals only with objects of type Node. It can do all sorts of things with these Nodes assuming that they have boolean comparisons overloaded properly. The thing is, I want to use this List class with a special kind of Node called a Term (an algebraic term with a coefficient and an exponent or degree). How do I tell my List class to use the Term functions (Term has special versions of the Print() function and comparison operators) even though it deals with the Terms using Node pointers? For example, my Print() is something like:

```
Node* walker=head;
while(walker)
{
     walker->Print();
     walker=walker->next;
}
```

Except there is no Node::Print(), I want it to call Term::Print()! Do I have to make a whole new List class to deal with Term class objects?

Comment: Please add language tag (probably C++)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of Polymorphism. You can add a function Print() to your Node class just like WhozCraig suggested. (Please read up Virtual Functions and Abstract classes in C++.) You can make Print() a virtual function. You can decide whether you want to make Print() a pure virtual function. If it's a pure virtual function, it will be declared like this in the base class.

```
class Node{
  virtual void Print() = 0;
  // If you don't want this to be pure virtual 
  // You can give a generic definition
}
```

In this case, since you did not define Print() in the base class, each derived class which is not meant to be abstract, must implement this method. Thus, the Term class can derive from Node class and implement it's Print() method accordingly :) And you can use the base class pointer to call this function. If in the future you decide to subclass Node and add a different implementation of Print(), you don't have to change Node at all :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This did help a lot. But now it gets more complicated, as I want to be able to use boolean comparison operators on Term objects using a Node pointer. For example, `if (*nodeptr1 >= *nodeptr2) {foo();}` where nodeptr1 and nodeptr2 point to objects of type Term which are derived from the Node class. I've put virtual bool functions in the Node class, and then declared and defined them in the Term class, but it still says the Term functions are abstract. Confusing!

Answer (score 0):

You're already diverging from usual list design - would recommend using templates instead of deriving from `Node` class.  You then would want a `foreach` method which will do an operation on each node, in this case `print`.  Strongly recommend using the C++ standard library containers instead of coding all this "raw".

Another option (less standard and with design flaws) would be to derive out a `PrintList` that will call the `Print` function, and it will need to be templated or to be done in terms of `Term` nodes as the compiler will expect this function.

Comment: It's for an assignment where we are to build a linked list class and then use inheritance to adapt the class to different types of nodes (polynomials, lists of names, etc). I'm guessing for each case I should directly modify the node class to include appropriate changes for each use... and I don't yet understand how to do templates, as we haven't yet covered those in the course.

Comment: Then I'd head right for them, as they are the appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: Agreeing with DeadMG, essentially if you're not going to use templates then you're going to have to do something that's poor design or incorrect or bad practice anyway, so not really much point in avoiding duplicating a class.

Answer (score 0):

Three choices:-

In the real world, you would use [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) or a similar container class

Or, you can add Print() as a virtual method to Node, (and make it abstract, potentially)

```
class Node {
  ...
  virtual void Print() = 0;
}
```

Or, you can use cast the Node* to a Term*

```
    Term *t = boost::polymorphic_cast<Term*>(walker);
    t->Print();
```